# wpa_supplicant - Why BSSID is coming as 00:00:00:00:00:00 after failed Roaming attempt, Is it a Bug or expected behavious in wpa-supplicant?

Tags: wpa-supplicant

[wpa_supplicant] Why BSSID is coming as 00:00:00:00:00:00  after failed Roaming attempt, Is it a Bug or expected behavious in wpa-supplicant?

After triggering ROAM operation (wpa_cli ROAM ) to a specific bssid, The reassociation got failed due to "WPA: Failed to select WPA/RSN"  error , But after this previous connection was maintained and able to connect to outside network, But BSSID was set to 00:00:00:00:00, Is this expected behavior,

```
Selected interface 'wlan0'
bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00
freq=5805
ssid=my_ssid
id=1
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=CCMP
group_cipher=CCMP
key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
wpa_state=COMPLETED
ip_address=169.254.113.222
address=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:x
uuid=amu_uuid
ieee80211ac=1
```

This is due to the memset in function sme_send_authentication() wpa_supplicant/sme.c , I just moved the place of memset to bit later part before sending the Auth request. Now its keeps the BSSID as the previous bssid itself and connection is maintained. Is it a Bug from wpa-supplicant or its an expected behavior. ?

More details : -

wpa_supplicant version - 2.7 ,

Steps to reproduce,
 1. Make sure that the client is connected to a bssid.
 2. WPA_CLI ROAM 
 3. see status wpa_cli status , ( Only on failure roam attempts)
Observations,
Roam failed due to below error

SME: Failed to set WPA key management and encryption suites

wpa_cli status is showing bssid as 00:00:00:00:00 
Connection is still maintained with my previous bssid.

Comment: If you fail an association, you will get an invalid BSSID and no IP address, it does not seem surprising. What is the real purpose of the question?

Comment: Yes, I agree with that if we are proceeding with a new association, But the case is different in case of roaming, If we fail during re association (during roaming) , The status was still completed with previous bssid, and all connection is maintained with previous bssid, even IP , Bcz we haven't disconnected from previous bssid during wpa_cli roam, But only the bssid was set to 0.  This is causing some abnormal behavior in my application. 

I need to know whether is there any specific reason for this behavior or is it a bug in wpa-supplicant?

Comment: You know you get 169.254.x.x when you also do not get an IP address, right? The premisses of this question seem wrong, at least from my point of view.

Comment: Hi Ribeiro, Thanks for sharing your thoughts, Yes, Its was set to 10.x.x.x network previously and it remains the same even after roaming attempt, Even we can ping google.com after this, Only issue is since re-association is failed bssid becomes 00:00:00:00.. But logically still the old connection is maintained.

Comment: We may have different ideas of connected. For me not being associated with a known BSSID and not having IP address is not being connected, and the question derives from you not wanting to realize that.